# Evaluate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n3^n\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)}{3^n\sqrt{n+1}+2^n}\right)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying to solve  $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n3^n\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)}{3^n\sqrt{n+1}+2^n}\right)$$

What I have tried is dividing the numerator and denominator by $3^n$ and then multiplying by the conjugate of the numerator but I don't obtain the answer which I think is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Is it possible to upload a picture?

Comment: Guys I don't see what's wrong with this question. He is a newcomer, asked a very clear question, formulated it nicely, used LaTeX formulas, and included clearly what he tried. Is the problem just that it is easy?

Comment: @PeterFranek I agree.

Comment: @PedagoStudy Also, if Peter Franek's answer helped you, you should upvote his answer and accept it (by clicking the check mark). And read the tour page: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour to better understand how this site operates. You're off to a good start though.

Answer (score 2):

What you suggest is correct. We have
$$
\ldots = 
\frac{n (n+1 - 1)}{\sqrt{n+1} (\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}) + (\frac{2}{3})^n (\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n})} = 
\frac{n}{n+1 + \sqrt{n^2 + n} + \text{small}} =
\ldots
$$